# Changing Properties of a static cell in a UITableView when view appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Im using the following code to attempt to update several static cells in my UITableView:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self reloadTableData];
}

- (void) reloadTableData {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:8];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    if ([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"canDeleteReceipts"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 0.2;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 1;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:8];
    cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    if ([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"canDeleteMileages"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 0.2;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 1;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:8];
    cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    if ([[userDefaults objectForKey:@"canDeleteAll"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 0.2;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 1;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

}
```

However it does't work, the code is called but does nothing.  Can anyone explain how I update the attributes of a static cell to achieve something like the above when the view appears?

The NSLog statement says that the cell is null.

Thanks

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the code in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` instead of your `reloadData` method.

Comment: @Jack Your welcome. Also please delete the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097726/uitableview-cell-appearance-update-not-working-iphone.  It is almost the same question you have asked for.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should cache your cells in an NSArray. When required, use the cell from that array and do not fetch from tableView.

Comment: How do I cache them in an array?  If I could access them in order to cache them in array wouldn't I be able to access them to perform the changes I require anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to reload the UITableView.

U have to give the message `[self.tableView reload]` in the `- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`   --> go to the DataSource of your table view i.e `-(UITableViewCell*)cellForRowatIndexPath:(NSIndexPath indexPath)`, there have your respective cell using the method- `[table cellForRowAtIndexPath]` and do what u r trying in the `- (void) reloadTableData` method of yours.

Comment: i.e when we reload the tableView, the data source methods r called again, where we can apply our changes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/index.php?title=ios/tutorials/Working_with_Tables_and_Cells/Part_5_-_Using_XCode,_Interface_Builder,_and_Storyboards).Go through this tutorial and make some changes according to your application.I think it works for you.